# Multiple subdirectory error with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am trying to use mod_rewrite manually in joomla, and I have the following Rule:

RewriteRule ^test/(t1|t2|t3)-(.*).html$ /index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=39&$1=$2 [L,NC]

So that I want the url

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=39&t1=foo
```

be displayed like

```
http://www.mysite.com/test/t1-foo.html
```

The rule works correctly, but when I am in the rewritten page the links like

```
 http://www.mysite.com/link.html
```

or 
     http://www.mysite.com/xxx/link.html

become

```
 http://www.mysite.com/test/link.html
```

or 
    http://www.mysite.com/xxx/test/link.html

respectively.

any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative urls in your page. Your page contains a link like `<a href="link.html">...` and the browser makes the links relative to the current 'folder', namely "test", so when clicked the browser loads `/test/link.html`.

You should just use root-relative urls. So the link should become more like `<a href="/link.html">...`. The leading '/' makes the browser load the page relative to the root ("/"), not relative to "/test/".